# Loading and running the event receiver class X from assembly Y failed. Could not load file or assembly '3rdParty.dll' or one of its dependencies.

Tags: 2013, event-receivers, deployment

I am trying deploy an event receiver that references a 3rd party dll. I have tried manually deploy the dll to GAC and include it in the Package of the solution to no avail.

I keep getting the error below:

> Loading and running the event receiver class X from assembly Y failed.
>   Could not load file or assembly '3rdParty.dll' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Has anyone experienced this before? I've also tried this with 2 separate DLL's not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you restart the process (e.g. IIS Application Pool) after deploying the 3rd party DLL manually?

Comment: I reset IIS after manually deploying to GAC and that did the trick.